# Remove key from dictionary

Tags: parse-platform

I want to remove key from dictionary in Parse cloud code, as we can achieve this by calling `removeObjectForKey:` in objective-C. Sorry as this is very simple, but I am new to js, and also not able to find out solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

As I have found the answer, so I am posting it for others, who want to do the same thing.By following command, we can do this

> delete dictionary[key];